# Strtol doesn't return the correct endptr - C

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, strtol

I have to parse data from file rows and for that I'm now using strtol() function.

I have for example this row in the text file: 1 abc

This is for example, an invalid row as this specific row has to contain one and only one integer value.

Now when I'm using strtol this way:

```
    FILE *fs;
    fs = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    char* ptr = NULL; // In case we have string except for the amount
    char lineInput[1024]; // The max line size is 1024
    fscanf(fs, "%s", lineInput);
    long numberOfVer = strtol(lineInput, &ptr, BASE);
    printf("%lu\n%s\n", numberOfVer, ptr); // Here I test the values, I expect to get 1 followed by newline and abc
    if (numberOfVer == 0 || *ptr != '\0') { // Not a positive number or there exists something after the amount!
        fprintf(stderr, INVALID_IN);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

But, the ptr string is not "abc" or " abc", it's an empty string...
Why is that? According to the documentation it has to be " abc".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf) (yes, I know it's self-promotion, but it answers the question -- use `fgets`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf("%s")` skips whitespace. So if you have the input `"1 abc"` and scan it in with

```
fscanf(fs, "%s", lineInput);
```

`lineInput` contents end up being `"1"` and the rest of the string stays in the input buffer ready for the next input operation.

The usual function for reading lines is `fgets()`

```
    FILE *fs;
    fs = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    char* ptr = NULL; // In case we have string except for the amount
    char lineInput[1024]; // The max line size is 1024
    // using fgets rather than fscanf
    fgets(lineInput, sizeof lineInput, fs);
    long numberOfVer = strtol(lineInput, &ptr, BASE);
    printf("%ld\n%s\n", numberOfVer, ptr); // Here I test the values, I expect to get 1 followed by newline and abc
    //      ^^^ numberOfVer is signed
    if (numberOfVer == 0 || *ptr != '\0') { // Not a positive number or there exists something after the amount!
        fprintf(stderr, INVALID_IN);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

Comment: `*ptr != '\0'` will likely always be true due to `'\n'`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica But if we don't have a line below?

Comment: @HelpMe: it's very unusual, in un*x systems, to have text files ending in something other than newline. The basic concept is that a line contains the `'\n'` character. For instance some compilers emit a diagnostic when fed a file that ends with `"}"` (not `"}\n"`).

Comment: @pmg If I have a text file which contains only one row "123" and nothing else, there is no a newline after this 123. So, when I use on this row strtol function, what is the value of endptr?

Comment: @HelpMe: in that (unusual) case `endptr` points to the `'\0'` just after the `'3'`. What I do often after `fgets()` is remove the newline if it exists: `lineInput[strcspn(lineInput, "\n")] = 0;`